# Android coordinator layout behavior infinitely calling onDependentViewChanged when anchor set

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm seeing the onDependentViewChanged function being called infinitely when I set the anchor in xml in my coordinator layout. If I don't set the anchor, this isn't called repeatedly and it is only called when I actually scroll (correct) but as soon as I set an anchor it is called infinitely as soon as the page loads, without touching the scroll.  But then my stuff isn't positioned where I want it.

I know I must be missing something but none of the examples discuss this problem. It only occurs when I try to set the anchor.

```
public class ViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<HeaderView> {

    private Context mContext;

    private int mStartMarginLeft;
    private int mEndMargintLeft;
    private int mMarginRight;
    private int mStartMarginBottom;
    private boolean isHide;

    public ViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, HeaderView child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof LinearLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, HeaderView child, View dependency) {
        shouldInitProperties(child, dependency);

        int maxScroll = 100;//((AppBarLayout) dependency).getTotalScrollRange();
        float percentage = Math.abs(dependency.getY()) / (float) maxScroll;

        float childPosition = dependency.getHeight()
                + dependency.getY()
                - child.getHeight()
                - (getToolbarHeight() - child.getHeight()) * percentage / 2;


        childPosition = childPosition - mStartMarginBottom * (1f - percentage);
        Log.d("CHILD POSTION ", "" + childPosition);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        lp.leftMargin = (int) (percentage * mEndMargintLeft) + mStartMarginLeft;
        lp.rightMargin = mMarginRight;
        child.setLayoutParams(lp);

        child.setY(childPosition);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (isHide && percentage < 1) {
                child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isHide = false;
            } else if (!isHide && percentage == 1) {
                child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isHide = true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void shouldInitProperties(HeaderView child, View dependency) {

        if (mStartMarginLeft == 0)
            mStartMarginLeft = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_start_margin_left);

        if (mEndMargintLeft == 0)
            mEndMargintLeft = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_end_margin_left);

        if (mStartMarginBottom == 0)
            mStartMarginBottom = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_start_margin_bottom);

        if (mMarginRight == 0)
            mMarginRight = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_end_margin_right);

    }


    public int getToolbarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            result = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGreen"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    >
                </LinearLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    >
                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
                        layout="@layout/header_view"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        />
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardConstraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp"/>
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/pager_indicator_selector_gray"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/float_header_view"
            layout="@layout/header_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="com.test.ViewBehavior"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top"

            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```